# Running multiple processes on a single Heroku dyno

Tags: ruby, heroku, sass, jekyll

I have a Heroku app, where I use Jekyll. My `Procfile` looks like this:

```
web: jekyll serve --port $PORT
```

I also want to use SASS, but if I add to `Procfile`, I'll need two dynos, which is too costly for me now:

```
sass: sass style.scss style.css
web: jekyll serve --port $PORT
```

Can I add second process but still stay on one dyno? What's the easiest way to do this for a developer with minimal Ruby experience?

I'm interested in any processes, Jekyll and SASS are just for example.

Answer (score 3):

SASS is not supposed to be compiled in production, it is a gigantic performance penalty that gives you no benefit.

So the short answer is: **you should not do that**. Instead, precompile SASS before or during deployment and serve static CSS in production.

If there is some exotic reason that justifies compiling SASS realtime (you should totally share what it is!), consider using either of those:

- [Jekyll Asset Pipeline](https://github.com/matthodan/jekyll-asset-pipeline#jekyll-asset-pipeline)
- [generator_scss.rb](https://gist.github.com/parkr/2874934) (requires Compass)

Sorry if it won't work for you, i haven't tried it myself.

PS Also consider changing your hosting provider. Heroku is a powerful tool, but it is extremely pricey. Have a look for example at [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/pricing). Those are pure VPS that come with no Ruby/Node magic preconfigured, but with a VPS you're not limited to "one dyno" or anything. And the difference in prices is huge.

Comment: Thanks for the hosting provider tip! I want to do this to remove a compile step and, therefore, need for Ruby on a local machine.

Comment: There is a lot of info on that. You should totally google it up: https://www.google.com/#output=search&q=heroku+jekyll+compass

Comment: I did. :) But I'm asking about multiple processes on one dyno, Jekyll and SASS are just for example. I probably should add this to the question.